# Maximum problem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Find the maximum of $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$.
Under the conditions $ \dfrac{x^2}{4} + \dfrac{y^2}{5} +\dfrac{z^2}{25} = 1 $ and $x+y-z=0$.
Using the Lagrange method.
I understand how to use the method but when i apply it appears very ugly equations and i can't find the points where $f$ is maximized.

Can someone help me to see a clean form to solve with Lagrange method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this out with a straightforward single-multiplier solution to see if I was working it out correctly.  It helps somewhat in dealing with the ellipsoid to multiply its equation through to avoid having to deal so much with fractions, thus $ \ 25x^2 + 20y^2 + 4z^2 = 100$ .  In that approach, it really does work out best to reduce the equations to two variables, as **lab bhattacharjee** did, so that we are seeking to maximize $ \ f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + (x+y)^2 \ $ , subject to the constraint $g(x,y) = 25x^2 + 20y^2 + 4(x + y)^2 - 100 \ = \ 29x^2 + 8xy + 24y^2 - 100$ .  Making use of the single multiplier $ \ \lambda \ $ leaves one confronted with

$$4x + 2y \ = \ \lambda \cdot (58x \ + \ 8y) \ , \ 2x + 4y \ = \ \lambda \cdot (8x \ + \ 48y) \ , $$

which one must grapple with in connection to the other available equations as best one can.  As there is no general method for solving systems of *nonlinear* equations, one can lose a lot of time looking for a resolution of this system.  (I had also tried this using all three coordinate variables, which does not improve the situation.)  I found that this led basically in the same direction as **lab bhattacharjee** has already presented, so I'll say nothing further about that.

Since we do have *two* constraint equations, we can use the Lagrange method with two multipliers, $\lambda \ \text{and} \ \mu$ .  For this, we will work with all three coordinate variables, so we wish to maximize $f(x,y,z) \ = \ x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ , subject to the constraint functions $g(x,y,z) \ = \ 25x^2 + 20y^2 + 4z^2 - 100 \ $ and $h(x,y,z) \ = \ x + y - z \ $ .  The Lagrange equation in this approach becomes  $ \ \nabla f \ = \ \lambda \cdot \nabla g \ + \ \mu \cdot \nabla h \ $ , giving us

$$ 2x \ = \ \lambda \cdot 50x \ + \ \mu \ \ , \ 2y \ = \ \lambda \cdot 40y \ + \ \mu \ \ , \ 2z \ = \ \lambda \cdot 8z \ + \ \mu \cdot (-1) \ . \ $$

The challenge remains in finding a method of resolving the system.  Attempting to solve the Lagrange equations for $ \ \lambda \ $ by eliminating $ \ \mu \ $ produces

$$x - y \ = \ \lambda \cdot (25x - 20y) \ , \ x + z \ = \ \lambda \cdot (25x + 4z) \ , \ y + z \ = \ \lambda \cdot (20y + 4z) \ , \   $$

which is every bit as troublesome as before.  We can solve instead for $ \ \mu \ $ , which is rather more promising:

$$\mu \ = \ x \cdot (2 - 50 \lambda) \ = \ y \cdot (2 - 40 \lambda) \ = \ z \cdot (8 \lambda - 2) \ . \ \ \mathbf{[1]} $$

Rather than put this into the equation for the ellipsoid, it is more helpful to insert it into the equation for the plane, yielding

$$z \ = \ x + y \ \Rightarrow \  z \ = \ (\frac{8 \lambda - 2}{2 - 50 \lambda}) \cdot z \ + \  (\frac{8 \lambda - 2}{2 - 40 \lambda}) \cdot z \  $$

$$\Rightarrow \  (2 - 50 \lambda) \cdot (2 - 40 \lambda) \ = \ [ \ (2 - 40 \lambda)  +  (2 - 50 \lambda) \ ] \cdot (8 \lambda - 2)   $$

$$\Rightarrow \ 2720 \cdot \lambda^2 \ - \ 392 \cdot \lambda \ + \ 12 \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ \lambda \ = \ \frac{392 \ \pm \ 152}{5440} \ = \ \frac{1}{10} \ , \ \frac{3}{68} \ .  $$

We may already suspect what getting two values for $\ \lambda \ $ might mean, particularly if we have an idea of what the graphical situation looks like (the x- and y-axis arrows are visible here, as we view "below" z = x + y):

[image]

Inserting $\ \lambda \ = \ \frac{1}{10} \ $ into equation **[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d03lM.jpg)** above gives us

$$-3x \ = \ -2y \ = \ -1.2z \ \Rightarrow \ 15x \ = \ 10y \ = \ 6z \ \Rightarrow \ y \ = \ \frac{3}{2} x \ , \ z \ = \ \frac{5}{2} x$$

$$\Rightarrow \ 25x^2 \ + \ 20 \cdot \frac{9}{4} \cdot x^2 \ + \ 4 \cdot \frac{25}{4} \cdot x^2 \ = \ 100 \ \Rightarrow \ x^2 \ = \frac{100}{95} $$

$$\Rightarrow \ x \ = \ \pm \frac{10}{\sqrt{95}} \ , \ y \ = \ \pm \frac{15}{\sqrt{95}} \ , \ z \ = \ \pm \frac{25}{\sqrt{95}} \ , \  $$

(which does check against equation [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d03lM.jpg) and the ellipsoid equation).  We find (perhaps surprisingly) an exact value for $ \ f \ $ of

$$x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ + \ z^2 \ = \ \frac{100}{95} \ + \ \frac{225}{95} \ + \ \frac{625}{95} \ = \ \frac{950}{95} \ = \ 10 \ . \ (!)$$

[Since $ \ f \ $ is the square of distance from the origin, we should well expect two points, on the ellipse of intersection between the plane and the ellipsoid, that produce the same value.]

The other result, $\ \lambda \ = \ \frac{3}{68} \ $ produces

$$7x \ = \ -8y \ = \ 56z \ \Rightarrow \ y \ = \ -\frac{7}{8}x \ , \ z \ = \ \frac{1}{8}x $$

$$\Rightarrow \ x \ = \ \pm \frac{80}{2 \sqrt{626}} \ , \ y \ = \ \mp \frac{70}{2 \sqrt{626}} \ , \ z \ = \ \pm \frac{10}{2 \sqrt{626}}  $$

$$\Rightarrow \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ + \ z^2 \ = \ \frac{11400}{2584}  \ \approx \ 4.4119 \ , $$

which would be the minimum value for $ \ f \ $ on the intersection ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

So, $z=x+y$

$\implies x^2+y^2+z^2=x^2+y^2+(x+y)^2=2x^2+2y^2+2xy$

and $\frac {x^2}4+\frac{y^2}5+\frac{z^2}{25}$ becomes $\frac{29x^2+8xy+24y^2}{100}$

Using [Lagrange multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier),

$$f(x,y)=2x^2+2y^2+2xy-100a\left(\frac{29x^2+8xy+24y^2}{100}\right)$$
$$=(2-29a)x^2+(2-24a)y^2+(2-8a)xy$$

So, $f_x=2x(2-29a)+(2-8a)y$ and $f_y=(2-24a)2y+(2-8a)x$

For the extreme values of $f, f_x=f_y=0$

If $y=0,29x^2=100\implies x^2+y^2+z^2=2x^2+2y^2+2xy=2x^2=\frac{200}{29}$

If $x=0,24y^2=100\implies x^2+y^2+z^2=2x^2+2y^2+2xy=2y^2=\frac{2\cdot100}{24}=\frac{25}3$

If $xy\ne0,$ find $a$ comparing values of $\frac xy$ from $2x(2-29a)+(2-8a)y=0$ and $(2-24a)2y+(2-8a)x=0$

Now use [Second partial derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test)